# Maintaining website with Git and more

Tags: git, web, permissions

I have a static website filled with documentation and reference material for my team and future users (we're up in coming, shown here with me trying to setup a useful and viable website system).

The site contains various static pages (note: by static I just mean HTML documents) in various directories that together are packages of documentation, or project homepages/documentation.

I would like each project homepage or notable collection of pages/documentation to be a git repository. The repositories should only be able to be pushed to by project maintainers and selective people, but should be able to be cloned by anyone (so users can quickly clone a documentation repository or something). This eliminates FTP and similar annoying things.

So with this goal I have a couple of issues:

- What do I use to determine who can push to these repositories?
- The website is on a HDD mounted to /hdd1 how do I make it, its contents, and any added contents readable by apache and readable and writable by git without having to change the permissions of the entire directory every time. (Note: It's a Linux box (Ubuntu Server))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three kind of repositories.

- A cental bare repository for doing the access control.
- A non-bare one on your web server, pulling changes from the central one, updating the web site
- working copies for the contributers, where changes are made and pushed to the central repository.

For the central repository I would recommend some management/authentication [software](http://www.barryodonovan.com/index.php/2013/01/04/git-web-applications-aka-github-alternatives) like gitlab, gitolite, atlassian stash, gerrit, etc.

For updating your repository at the web server you could use a git hook at the central repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why can't I just have one?

Comment: With only one repository you cannot have any good access control. The only way would be using system permissions, allowing all authors shell access to the server and you really don't need any git for this. Using a central repository is much cleaner.